# @Transaction annotation not working with Global transactions but it is working for Local transactions

Tags: java, spring-batch, mybatis, jndi, rollback

We have used class level @transaction annotations to enable rollback mechanism in Spring batch.
The code is given below:

**@Transactional(rollbackFor = { DaoException.class, LogicRuntimeException.class })
public class ClassA{}**

where, it is expected that whenever any exception is being thrown from any method from ClassA, it should rollback all other transactions which is already executed (but not committed) from the following class.

But it is observed that when we are executing this using local setting, it is working perfectly but when the WAR is deployed to the server, in which Global setting is used, the rollback is not working at all.

The main difference is for local system, we have used JDBC:
**<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />**

and for server (global) setup, we have used JNDI:
**org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean**

Also, FYI,
to set auto-commit to false, the following common code exists for both local and global setup:

**SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
session.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);**

where, sqlSessionFactory is object for "org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" where all the mappers and data source are linked.

Just wanna know if I am missing any specific configuration for Global transaction, probably to set auto-commit as false or any other details.

Comment: When you say "...it should rollback all other transactions which is already executed" -- Are these other transactions' propagation marked as REQUIRED, SUPPORTS, or MANDATORY, or nothing at all? Also, are all transactions using the same/single datasource or multiple ones?

Comment: 1. These transactions are REQUIRED by default.
2. YES, all transactions using the single datasource.

Comment: I suspect there's something with the Spring configuration, but it's unclear from the details. What do you mean by "Global setting"?

Comment: Actually, I have 2 data source with same name which is managed by profiles (-Dspring.profiles.active), only difference is that in global setting, JNDI is used while in local setting JDBC is used. So, if I say rollback is working in local but not global so it means that it is working in JDBC but not JNDI setup but couldn't figure out why is that happening, if we need any extra setting for JNDI in spring configuration cz it is working fine in JDBC for same setting?